# Returning FileResult does not pick up MIME type in IE9

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-9

I have a method on a controller which returns files

```
public FileResult DownloadFile(int id)
{
    var file = _repository.GetInidividualFile(id);
    return File(file.FileBinary, file.ContentType, file.FileName);
}
```

The file object is returning the values back correctly but IE9 isn't picking up the content type. The current list of file types I have are:

'application/pdf'

'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'

'application/vnd.ms-excel'

all other browsers seem to be working fine but IE just seems to ignore the extension. The problem I have is that because the file has been downloaded without an extension, the user is prompted to select which application to open the file with but they will have no idea.

I have tried in firefox, chrome, safari and opera and everything is fine

Here's the view of the debugger showing the values being returned

[image: debug]

Here's the output from fiddler showing the content type:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0

Date: Tue, 19 Feb 2013 10:16:41 GMT

X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319

X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0

Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Provisioning Tool"

Cache-Control: private

Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

Content-Length: 491470

Connection: Close

Comment: Have you checked what something like Fiddler is showing for the content type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some messing around I have finally found what this is. IE expects the extension on the file name despite having the content type. So,

```
return File(file.FileBinary, "application/pdf", "test");
```

won't work, but

```
return File(file.FileBinary, "application/pdf", "test.pdf");
```

does.